# Problem building tensorflow model from huggingface weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I need to work with the pretrained BERT model (`'dbmdz/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased'`) from Huggingface with Tensorflow (at [this](https://huggingface.co/dbmdz/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased) link).

After reading this on the website,

> Currently only PyTorch-Transformers compatible weights are available. If you need access to TensorFlow checkpoints, please raise an issue!

I raised the issue and promptly a download link to an archive containing the following files was given to me. The files are the following ones:

```sh
$ ls bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/
config.json                    model.ckpt.index               vocab.txt
model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 model.ckpt.meta
```

I'm now trying to load the model and work with it but everything I tried failed.

I tried following [this](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/load-weight-from-local-ckpt-file/3854) suggestion from an Huggingface discussion site:

```py
bert_folder = str(Config.MODELS_CONFIG.BERT_CHECKPOINT_DIR) # folder in which I have the files extracted from the archive
from transformers import BertConfig, TFBertModel
config = BertConfig.from_pretrained(bert_folder) # this gets loaded correctly
```

After this point I tried several combinations in order to load the model but always unsuccessfully.

eg:

```
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("../../models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/model.ckpt.index", config=config)

model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("../../models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/model.ckpt.index", config=config, from_pt=True)

model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("../../models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/model.ckpt.index", config=config, from_pt=True)

model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("../../models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased", config=config, local_files_only=True)
```

Always results in this error:

```
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/model.ckpt.index/resolve/main/tf_model.h5
...
...
OSError: Can't load weights for '../../models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/model.ckpt.index'. Make sure that:

- '../../models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/model.ckpt.index' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or '../../models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/model.ckpt.index' is the correct path to a directory containing a file named one of tf_model.h5, pytorch_model.bin.
```

So my question is: **How can I load this pre-trained BERT model from those files and use it in tensorflow?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following snippet to load `dbmdz/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased` in `tensorflow`.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFBertModel
model_name = "dbmdz/bert-base-italian-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

If you want to load from the given `tensorflow checkpoint`, you could try like this:

```
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("../../models/pretrained/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased/model.ckpt.index", config=config, from_tf=True)
```

Comment: I already tried with `from_tf` and it does not work

Comment: What about the first suggestion? Does it work that way?

Comment: Want to confirm whether you actually tried `from_tf` because your post says `from_pt` twice and no `from_tf`.

Comment: I only listed some of the combinations that I tried, but yes, I already with `from_tf` and it does not work. 
The first suggestion works on colab but I have problems with the from pretrained function in my local environment if the dataset has to be downloaded and it is not on the local machine due to some problems with JupyterLab so I still need a way to load the model from the files on my machine.

Comment: (1) The first suggestion is not related to the dataset or any platform, you just need the right version of transformers in your environment. (2) Didn't come across any huggingface documentation where they load model from `.ckpt` of `tensorflow`. Instead you could use `convert_bert_original_tf_checkpoint_to_pytorch.py` to convert your `tf` checkpoint to `pytorch` and then load using `from_pt=True`, [see](https://huggingface.co/transformers/converting_tensorflow_models.html). (3) Tensorflow checkpoints are actually present in the same repo with the name `tf_model.h5`, loadable using `from_tf`.