# Problem with inputs when building a model with TFBertModel and AutoTokenizer from HuggingFace's transformers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm trying to build the model illustrated in this picture:
[image]

I obtained a pre-trained BERT and respective tokenizer from HuggingFace's `transformers` in the following way:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFBertModel
model_name = "dbmdz/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
bert = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

The model will be fed a sequence of italian tweets and will need to determine if they are ironic or not.

I'm having problems building the initial part of the model, which takes the inputs and feeds them to the tokenizer in order to get a representation I can feed to BERT.

I can do it outside of the model-building context:

```
my_phrase = "Ciao, come va?"
# an equivalent version is tokenizer(my_phrase, other parameters)
bert_input = tokenizer.encode(my_phrase, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors='tf', max_length=110, padding='max_length', truncation=True) 
attention_mask = bert_input > 0
outputs = bert(bert_input, attention_mask)['pooler_output']
```

but I'm having troubles building a model that does this. Here is the code for building such a model (the problem is in the first 4 lines ):

```
def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  encoder_inputs = tokenizer(text_input, return_tensors='tf', add_special_tokens=True, max_length=110, padding='max_length', truncation=True)
  outputs = bert(encoder_inputs)
  net = outputs['pooler_output']
  
  X = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(net)
  X = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([X, input_layer])
  X = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(20)(X)
  X = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.4)(X)
  X = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(X)
  X = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(X)
  X = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(X)
  X = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(X)

  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs = X) 
  
  return model
```

And when I call the function for creating this model I get this error:

> text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).

One thing I thought was that maybe I had to use the `tokenizer.batch_encode_plus` function which works with lists of strings:

```py
class BertPreprocessingLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, tokenizer, maxlength):
    super().__init__()
    self._tokenizer = tokenizer
    self._maxlength = maxlength
  
  def call(self, inputs):
    print(type(inputs))
    print(inputs)
    tokenized = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(inputs, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors='tf', max_length=self._maxlength, padding='max_length', truncation=True)
    return tokenized

def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  encoder_inputs = BertPreprocessingLayer(tokenizer, 100)(text_input)
  outputs = bert(encoder_inputs)
  net = outputs['pooler_output']
  # ... same as above
```

but I get this error:

> batch_text_or_text_pairs has to be a list (got <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>)

and beside the fact I haven't found a way to convert that tensor to a list with a quick google search, it seems weird that I have to go in and out of tensorflow in this way.

I've also looked up on the huggingface's [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#tfbertmodel) but there is only a single usage example, with a single phrase, and what they do is analogous at my "out of model-building context" example.

EDIT:

I also tried with `Lambda`s in this way:

```
tf.executing_eagerly()

def tokenize_tensor(tensor):
  t = tensor.numpy()
  t = np.array([str(s, 'utf-8') for s in t])
  return tokenizer(t.tolist(), return_tensors='tf', add_special_tokens=True, max_length=110, padding='max_length', truncation=True)

def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  
  encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tokenize_tensor, name='tokenize')(text_input)
  ...
  
  outputs = bert(encoder_inputs)
```

but I get the following error:

> 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

EDIT 2:

I also tried the approach suggested by @mdaoust of wrapping everything in a `tf.py_function` and got this error.

```py
def py_func_tokenize_tensor(tensor):
  return tf.py_function(tokenize_tensor, [tensor], Tout=[tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32])
```

> eager_py_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Tout'

Then I defined Tout as the type of the value returned by the tokenizer:

`transformers.tokenization_utils_base.BatchEncoding`

and got the following error:

> Expected DataType for argument 'Tout' not <class
> 'transformers.tokenization_utils_base.BatchEncoding'>

Finally I unpacked the value in the BatchEncoding in the following way:

```py
def tokenize_tensor(tensor):
  t = tensor.numpy()
  t = np.array([str(s, 'utf-8') for s in t])
  dictionary = tokenizer(t.tolist(), return_tensors='tf', add_special_tokens=True, max_length=110, padding='max_length', truncation=True)
  #unpacking
  input_ids = dictionary['input_ids']
  tok_type = dictionary['token_type_ids']
  attention_mask = dictionary['attention_mask']
  return input_ids, tok_type, attention_mask
```

And get an error in the line below:

```py
...
outputs = bert(encoder_inputs)
```

> ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now I solved by taking the tokenization step out of the model:

```py
def tokenize(sentences, tokenizer):
    input_ids, input_masks, input_segments = [],[],[]
    for sentence in sentences:
        inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(sentence, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=128, pad_to_max_length=True, return_attention_mask=True, return_token_type_ids=True)
        input_ids.append(inputs['input_ids'])
        input_masks.append(inputs['attention_mask'])
        input_segments.append(inputs['token_type_ids'])        
        
    return np.asarray(input_ids, dtype='int32'), np.asarray(input_masks, dtype='int32'), np.asarray(input_segments, dtype='int32')
```

The model takes two inputs which are the first two values returned by the tokenize funciton.

```py
def build_classifier_model():
   input_ids_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), name='input_token', dtype='int32')
   input_masks_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), name='masked_token', dtype='int32') 

   embedding_layer = bert(input_ids_in, attention_mask=input_masks_in)[0]
...
   model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids_in, input_masks_in], outputs = X)

   for layer in model.layers[:3]:
     layer.trainable = False
   return model
```

I'd still like to know if someone has a solution which integrates the tokenization step inside the model-building context so that an user of the model can simply feed phrases to it to get a prediction or to train the model.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to achieve this?

Comment: It's been a while but if I remember well, I never quite managed to achieve this. You can check my code [here](https://github.com/gerzin/irony-and-sarcasm-detector-italian/tree/main/models), the models are in bertgru.py and bertlstm.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71411065/use-sentence-transformers-inside-of-a-keras-model have a look at this too!

Answer (score 0):

> text input must of type str (single example), List[str] (batch or single pretokenized example) or List[List[str]] (batch of pretokenized examples).

Solution to the above error:

Just use `text_input = 'text'`

instead of

`text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')`

Comment: That could be probably be a separate question with some more description :)

Comment: I just found out that this wasn't a solution to the error, in this way you just pass the string "text" to the tokenizer, which will tokenize it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not TensorFlow compatible.

https://huggingface.co/dbmdz/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased#model-weights

```
Currently only PyTorch-Transformers compatible weights are available. If you need access to TensorFlow checkpoints, please raise an issue!
```

But remember that some things are easier if you don't use keras's functional-model-api. That's what `got <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>` is complaining about.

Try passing a `tf.Tensor` to see if that works.
What happens when you try:

```
text_input = tf.constant('text')
```

Try writing your model as a subclass of model.

Comment: That's not a problem at all, I already have the tensorflow version working as it can be seen in the first two snippets of code. I got the tensorflow model as they answered me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925863/problem-building-tensorflow-model-from-huggingface-weights). My problem is that the tokenizer only accepts strings or list of strings and not tensors. I tried extracting the strings from the tensors, unsuccessfully.

Comment: I see your point. Let me try again.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, my first answer was wrong.

The problem is that tensorflow has two types of tensors. Eager tensors (these have a value). And "symbolic tensors" or "graph tensors" that don't have a value, and are just used to build up a calculation.

Your `tokenize_tensor` function expects an  eager tensor. Only eager tensors have a `.numpy()` method.

```
def tokenize_tensor(tensor):
  t = tensor.numpy()
  t = np.array([str(s, 'utf-8') for s in t])
  return tokenizer(t.tolist(), return_tensors='tf', add_special_tokens=True, max_length=110, padding='max_length', truncation=True)
```

But keras `Input` is a symbolic tensor.

```
text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string, name='text')  
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tokenize_tensor, name='tokenize')(text_input)
```

To fix this, you can use `tf.py_function`. It works in graph mode, and will call the wrapped function with eager tensors when the graph is executed, instead of passing it the graph-tensors while the graph is being constructed.

```
def py_func_tokenize_tensor(tensor):
  return tf.py_function(tokenize_tensor, [tensor])

...

encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(py_func_tokenize_tensor, name='tokenize')(text_input)
```

Comment: With this approach I had problems with the definition of `Tout`

Answer (score 0):

Found this [Use `sentence-transformers` inside of a keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71411065/use-sentence-transformers-inside-of-a-keras-model) and this amazing articles https://www.philschmid.de/tensorflow-sentence-transformers, which explain you how to do what you're trying to achieve.

The first one is using the py_function approach, the second uses tf.Model to wrap everything into model classes.

Hope this helps anyone arriving here in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use `tf.py_function` correctly to create a model that takes string as an input:

```py
model_name = "dbmdz/bert-base-italian-xxl-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
bert = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

def build_model():
    
    text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')

    def encode_text(text):
        inputs = [tf.compat.as_str(x) for x in text.numpy().tolist()]
        tokenized = tokenizer(
            inputs,
            return_tensors='tf',
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=110,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True)
        return tokenized['input_ids'], tokenized['attention_mask']
        
    input_ids, attention_mask = tf.py_function(encode_text, inp=[text_input], Tout=[tf.int32, tf.int32])
    
    input_ids = tf.ensure_shape(input_ids, [None, 110])
    attention_mask = tf.ensure_shape(attention_mask, [None, 110])
    
    outputs = bert(input_ids, attention_mask)
    
    net = outputs['last_hidden_state']

    # Some other layers, this part is not important
    x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(net)
    x = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name='classifier'))(x)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=x)
```

I use `last_hidden_state` instead of `pooler_output`, that's where outputs for each token in the sequence are located. (See discussion [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/7540#issuecomment-704155218) on difference between `last_hidden_state` and `pooler_output`). We usually use `last_hidden_state` when doing token level classification (e.g. *named entity recognition*).

To use `pooler_output` would be even simpler, e.g:

```py
net = outputs['pooler_output']
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name='classifier')(net)
return tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=x)
```

`pooler_output` can be used in simpler classification problems (like irony detection), but of course it's still possible to use `last_hidden_state` to create more powerful models. (When you use `bert(input_ids_in, attention_mask=input_masks_in)[0]` in your solution, it actually returns `last_hidden_state`.)

Making sure the model works:

```py
model = build_model()
my_phrase = "Ciao, come va?"
model(tf.constant([my_phrase]))

>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 110, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=...>,
```

Making sure HuggingFace part of the model is trainable:

```py
model.summary(show_trainable=True)
```